# How can I show coordinates by grid in TikZ automatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I have the following `TikZ` code which draws a grid and shows the coordinates. 
To display the coordinates I am using the loop `foreach`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=.2] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\draw[help lines,line width=.6pt,step=1] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
 \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-2) {\x};
\foreach \y in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
 \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way do simplify the code in this way that I have a key like `show coordinates` (maybe `step coordinates/.initial=step` ):

```
\draw[help lines,step=.2,show coordinates=true] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
```

Or a modification of the command `grid` like

```
\draw[help lines,step=.5] (-2,-2) gridwithcoordinates (7,4);
```

[image]

By using `pstricks` it is very simple with the command `\psgrid`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(7,4)
\psgrid
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

*Bonus*: How can I set a larger line width for the help lines at the integer coordinates (see picture above)?

<sub>(I don't know the correct words ;-) )</sub>

Comment: Maybe this is a nice idea for a new package ala `tikz-grid`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Why do you think `best-practice` isn't the correct tag?

Comment: Forgive me, I should have added a comment. I thought that this is a question of the type *"is there an easier way of doing this"*, rather than *"what is the preferred way of accomplishing this"*. The latter is the kind of question I would put that tag on. If you (or anyone else) feel that I'm wrong about this, don't hesitate to add it back in.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I have no problem with this. I only want to understand. Sometimes (ok often) I read the words with no understanding ;-)

Comment: I added the code to change the line widths.

Comment: Have you read this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14225/is-there-the-easiest-way-to-toggle-show-hide-navigational-grids-in-tikz?

Comment: @CounterTerrorist: This seems to be equivalent but the implementation isn't what I looking for. It uses the whole bounding box. I want to draw a grid specified by the coordinates of draw.

Comment: Check this site http://michaelgoerz.net/blog/2009/07/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz/

Comment: @RobertSchumacher: This is a technic of drawing something but not a "stand alone" solution. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `to path`s to execute arbitrary code in the guise of a simple command.  If the preamble were hidden away in a package, the invocation would just be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) to[grid with coordinates] (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The sneaky trick is to use the fact that the `to path` declaration can contain arbitrary code via a `\pgfextra` command.  With that, it's just a matter of grabbing the starting and ending coordinates (which are encoded as `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget`) and then using your original code (which I assume you were reasonably happy with) as the code to be executed.

With the preamble, the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\grd@save@target#1{%
  \def\grd@target{#1}}
\def\grd@save@start#1{%
  \def\grd@start{#1}}
\tikzset{
  grid with coordinates/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \edef\grd@@target{(\tikztotarget)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@target\grd@@target\relax
        \edef\grd@@start{(\tikztostart)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@start\grd@@start\relax
        \draw[minor help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \draw[major help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \grd@start
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xa}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@ya}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \grd@target
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xb}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yb}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xc}{\grd@xa + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yc}{\grd@ya + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
        \foreach \x in {\grd@xa,\grd@xc,...,\grd@xb}
        \node[anchor=north] at (\x,\grd@ya) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
        \foreach \y in {\grd@ya,\grd@yc,...,\grd@yb}
        \node[anchor=east] at (\grd@xa,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}};
      }
    }
  },
  minor help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step}
  },
  major help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major line width},
    step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}
  },
  grid with coordinates/.cd,
  minor step/.initial=.2,
  major step/.initial=1,
  major line width/.initial=2pt,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=.2] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\draw[help lines,line width=.6pt,step=1] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
 \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-2) {\x};
\foreach \y in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
 \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) to[grid with coordinates] (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Your original grid is included first for comparison.  I thickened the major lines on my version, by the way.)

The extra bits, and the stuff with the `@`s, is for processing the coordinates to figure out where to start and end the labelling.  The assumption is that we start at the first coordinate and work our way up according to the major step separation to the second coordinate.  So we need to process these coordinates to extract that information.  This means that the coordinates to the command can be any TikZ coordinate: we use `\tikz@scan@one@point` which is how TikZ itself parses coordinates.

One thing to note is the use of `\pgfmathprintnumber` to ensure that the labels are printed nicely.

The result is as follows:

[image: TikZ grid with labels]

Comment: Wow. Very nice solution.

Comment: ++++1 -- awesome. Will you create an extra library for CTAN?

Comment: Nice. I have to study this solution. My initial idea was to use to paths but I thought that it wasn't possible to change the pen style. One suggestion: change the `line cap` to `round`.

Comment: Awesome Andrew! `:)`

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Good idea.  Have you tested that?  If so, feel free to edit accordingly - might be a day or so before I get round to testing it.

Comment: @Andrew No I haven't tested it, but I'd imagine the corners of the coarser grid will look better. (So there's only need to set the `line cap` to `round` in the coarser grid.)

Comment: How can I don't show the numbers and I want grid all the page?

Comment: @toandhsp This is a very old question and answer. You will get a better response if you post a new question (link to this if you like).

Comment: Excellent tikz grid! I changed the line size to `0.5pt`, the grid line color to `gray!30`, the font size to `\scriptsize`, and forced math mode for the grid labels with `$ $`, and it works very well. Here: https://pastebin.com/LiY4Rifn

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly what you are looking for (no subgrid) but coordinates are shown.

[image: grid with coordinates]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@Get@x@coor#1,#2\tikz@sentinel{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(round(#1/1cm))}}
\def\tikz@Get@y@coor#1,#2\tikz@sentinel{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(round(#2/1cm))}}
\tikzset{%
  show grid integer coordinates/.style = {%
    decoration = {%
      show path construction, 
      moveto code = {%
        \expandafter\tikz@Get@x@coor\tikzinputsegmentfirst\tikz@sentinel
        \edef\tikz@tempa{\pgfmathresult}%
        \expandafter\tikz@Get@x@coor\tikzinputsegmentlast\tikz@sentinel
        \edef\tikz@tempb{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathparse{equal(\tikz@tempa,\tikz@tempb)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
        \node[anchor=north] at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) {%
          \tikz@tempa};
        \else
        \node[anchor=east] at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) {%
          \expandafter\tikz@Get@y@coor\tikzinputsegmentfirst\tikz@sentinel
          \pgfmathresult};
        \fi}},
    postaction = decorate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[show grid integer coordinates] (-2,2) grid (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The subgrid can be added with the same idea, but it goes too far... I don't know how to access to the upper right corner x coordinate: `\tikz@lastx` is set to `0.0pt` inside the moveto code.

[image: subgrid]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@Get@x@coor#1,#2\tikz@sentinel{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(round(#1/1cm))}}
\def\tikz@Get@y@coor#1,#2\tikz@sentinel{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(round(#2/1cm))}}
\tikzset{%
  show grid integer coordinates/.style = {%
    preaction = {%
      decoration = {%
        show path construction, 
        moveto code = {%
          \expandafter\tikz@Get@x@coor\tikzinputsegmentfirst\tikz@sentinel
          \edef\tikz@tempa{\pgfmathresult}%
          \expandafter\tikz@Get@x@coor\tikzinputsegmentlast\tikz@sentinel
          \edef\tikz@tempb{\pgfmathresult}%
          \pgfmathparse{equal(\tikz@tempa,\tikz@tempb)}%
          \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
          \node[anchor=north] at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) {%
            \tikz@tempa};
          \draw[help lines,step=.1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) grid
            ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)+(1,0)$);
          \else
            \node[anchor=east] at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) {%
              \expandafter\tikz@Get@y@coor\tikzinputsegmentfirst\tikz@sentinel\pgfmathresult};
          \fi}},
      decorate}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[show grid integer coordinates] (-2,2) grid (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I am sorry but there's no easy solution. First I tried using a `to path` but that doesn't let you change the line style:-( Next I tried implementing a dedicated command. This time the main problem is that in order to iterate over the coordinate labels, the labels should be integral, which isn't true in general. The following should work, but it requires coordinates consisting of two integers each; rationals and labels are not allowed. It should be possible to implement a macro that takes more general arguments but that would take too long.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}            
\usetikzlibrary{calc}        

\makeatletter
\newif\ifmygrid@coordinates
\tikzset{/mygrid/step line/.style={line width=0.80pt,draw=gray!80},
         /mygrid/steplet line/.style={line width=0.25pt,draw=gray!80}}
\pgfkeys{/mygrid/.cd,
         step/.store in=\mygrid@step,
         steplet/.store in=\mygrid@steplet,
         coordinates/.is if=mygrid@coordinates}
\def\mygrid@def@coordinates(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
    \def\mygrid@xlo{#1}%
    \def\mygrid@xhi{#3}%
    \def\mygrid@ylo{#2}%
    \def\mygrid@yhi{#4}%
}
\newcommand\DrawGrid[3][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/mygrid/.cd,coordinates=true,step=1,steplet=0.2,#1}%
    \draw[/mygrid/steplet line] #2 grid[step=\mygrid@steplet] #3;
    \draw[/mygrid/step line] #2 grid[step=\mygrid@step] #3;
    \mygrid@def@coordinates#2#3%
    \ifmygrid@coordinates%
        \draw[/mygrid/step line]
        \foreach \xpos in {\mygrid@xlo,...,\mygrid@xhi} {%
          (\xpos,\mygrid@ylo) -- ++(0,-3pt)
                              node[anchor=north] {$\xpos$}
        }
        \foreach \ypos in {\mygrid@ylo,...,\mygrid@yhi} {%
          (\mygrid@xlo,\ypos) -- ++(-3pt,0)
                              node[anchor=east] {$\ypos$}
        };
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawGrid{(-2,-1)}{(3,2)}
%\DrawGrid[coordinates=false]{(-2,-1)}{(3,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```