# TikZ horizontal parabola with path operation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know of e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410144/how-to-draw-the-parabola-with-equation-x-y2-2) or similar, but is there an option to draw a turned parabola just using the path operation?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,-1) parabola bend (1,0) (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rotate` !

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rotate=90] (-1,1) parabola bend (0,0) (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At first I was unsure about `rotate` because I have to match precise positioning of the end points and `rotate` seemed to break that, but I managed to get it working in my specific case. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a Bézier curve also `\draw[red,scale=1/3] (3,-3) .. controls (-1,-1) and (-1,1) .. (3,3);`. Check this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429938/9335) of mine.