# How are quadratic Bezier curves drawn by TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

I'm trying to understand how exactly Bezier curves are drawn by TikZ. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B%C3%A9zier_curves), the parametrization of a quadratic Bezier curve is given by `B(t) = (1 - t) ((1 - t) P0 + t P1) + t ((1 - t) P1 + t P2`. Consider the example `y = 2x^2`, going through the points `P0 = (0,0)` and `P2 = (1, 2)` (blue line below) which can be parametrized as `P(t) = (t, 2t^2)`

It is easy to calculate

```
B''(t) = 2 (P2 - 2 P1 + P0) = (2, 4) - 2P1
P''(t) = (0, 4)
```

From this I can calculate the *control* point `P1 = (1/2, 0)` by making `B''(t) = P''(t)`. The result is shown in red below

Clearly the curves are different, which means that the point `P1` is not the control point I am supposed to use. Or that the parametrization `B(t)` that wikipedia uses is not the one used by TikZ. The question is then: what is the actual parametrization used by TikZ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  decoration = {markings,
    mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red, opacity = 0.5] circle (0.05);}
  },
  ]

  \draw [help lines] (-1, -1) grid (2, 3);

  % parabola
  \draw[blue, thick] (0, 0) parabola (1, 2) node[left]{$y=2x^2$};
  \fill[blue, opacity = 0.5] (0.5, 0.5) circle (0.05);

  % bezier
  \draw[red, thick, postaction={decorate}] (0, 0) .. controls (0.5, 0) .. (1, 2) node[midway, right]{bezier};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am aware of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255234/how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-tikz), but I don't think it covers this question.

Comment: TikZ, as PDF and Postscript, uses *cubic* Bézier curves....

Comment: @PaulGaborit How is the statement `\draw (A) .. controls (B) .. (C);` interpreted by TikZ?

Comment: The complete syntax is `.. controls (c) and (d) ..`.  _If the  `and (d)` part is not given, `d` is assumed to be equal to `c`_ (cf.  p.149 pfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Comment: @PaulGaborit I see, I assumed that it used a quadratic curve, probably after reading `\pgfpathquadraticcurveto{support}{coordinate}`. Or does this one also use a cubic Bezier?

Comment: Quadratic curves are also replaced by cubic ones. The curve is not changing but the bounding box is tighter.

Comment: By the way the `parabola` in tikz [is not rally a parabola](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429938). If you want to draw `x^2` over `[0,1]` you can use a quadratic curve with control points `(0,0) (.5,0) (1,1)` or a cubic curve with control points `(0,0) (1/3,0) (2/3,1/3) (1,1)`.

Comment: The fact that `\draw (A) .. controls (B) .. (C);` is equivalent to `\draw (A) .. controls (B) and (B) .. (C);` and not to the quadratic `\draw (A) .. controls ($(A)!2/3!(B)$) and ($(B)!1/3!(C)$) .. (C);` is in my opinion a bad design choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Paul Gaborit said in his comments `(a) .. controls (b) .. (c)` is not a quadratic Bézier curve, but the cubic one `(a) .. controls (b) and (b) .. (c)`.

If you want to draw a quadratic curve in TikZ you can define your own `to path` style. Here is an an example of how to do it using `calc` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt,convert={density=1400}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  quadratic/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) .. controls
      ($#1!1/3!(\tikztostart)$) and ($#1!1/3!(\tikztotarget)$)
      .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={scale=2,text opacity=1}]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,4);
    \filldraw[fill opacity=.07]
        (0,0) coordinate[label=center:.](A)
      --(1,0) coordinate[label=center:.](B)
      --(2,4) coordinate[label=center:.](C);
    \draw[blue] (A)..controls (B)..(C);
    \draw[red,very thick] (A) to[quadratic={(B)}] (C);  % <- The quadratic curve
    \draw[white,domain=0:2] plot (\x,\x^2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you prefer a code that do not use `calc` and use the PGF command `\pgfpathquadraticcurveto` you can replace the style definition with :

```
\makeatletter
\def\pt@get#1{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax%
  \pgfpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\tikzset{
  quadratic/.code={
    \def\tikz@to@path{}% <- TikZ do nothing
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pt@get{#1}}{\pt@get{(\tikztotarget)}}% <- PGF insert the quadratic curve
  }
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

The QUADRATIC Bezier curve with 3 control points P0, P1, P2 is a special case of the CUBIC Bezier curve with 4 control points P0, (1/3 P0+2/3 P1), (2/3 P1+1/3 P2), P2. For example, if you want to draw the downwards arc of a parabola (quadratic Bezier) with control points (0,6), (3,6), (6,0), use the cubic control points
(0,6), (2,6), (4,4), (6,0), as in `\draw (0,6) .. controls (2,6) and (4,4) .. (6,0);`
The formula is obtained by comparing the coefficients for the two Bezier curves as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve