# Different xstep and ystep in TikZ with to[path] (precisely to[grid with coordinates])

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

As it's my first question, I want to say `hello` first!

I am using `[grid with coordinates]` code from Andrew Stacey answer [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39698/28771) for [How can I show coordinates by grid in TikZ automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/how-can-i-show-coordinates-by-grid-in-tikz-automatically).

I modified it a bit and tried to acquire different `major/minor lines xstep` and `ystep`, I ended with:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\def\grd@save@target#1{%
  \def\grd@target{#1}}
\def\grd@save@start#1{%
  \def\grd@start{#1}}
\tikzset{
  grid with coordinates/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \edef\grd@@target{(\tikztotarget)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@target\grd@@target\relax
        \edef\grd@@start{(\tikztostart)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@start\grd@@start\relax
        \draw[minor help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \draw[major help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \grd@start
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xa}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@ya}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \grd@target
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xb}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yb}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xc}{\grd@xa + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step x}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yc}{\grd@ya + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step y}}
        \foreach \x in {\grd@xa,\grd@xc,...,\grd@xb}
        \node[anchor=north] at (\x,\grd@ya) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
        \foreach \y in {\grd@ya,\grd@yc,...,\grd@yb}
        \node[anchor=east] at (\grd@xa,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}};
      }
    }
  },
  minor help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    gray,
    line cap =round,
    xstep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step x},
    ystep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step y}
  },
  major help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    line cap =round,
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major line width},
    xstep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step x},
    ystep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step y}
  },
  grid with coordinates/.cd,
  minor step x/.initial=.5,
  minor step y/.initial=.2,
  major step x/.initial=1,
  major step y/.initial=1,
  major line width/.initial=1pt,
}
\makeatother
```

What I need now is to specify `xstep` and `ystep` in actual `tikzpicture`, e.g. in code below I want to pass `xstep` and `ystep` (for minor and major lines separately) so that Fig. B gets `major lines xstep =0.2`.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=2]
    \draw (0,0) to[grid with coordinates] (5,1);    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A}\label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}    

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5,yscale=2]
    \draw (0,0) to[grid with coordinates] (1,1); %major step x =0.2
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{B}\label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I can't guess how to pass the parameters.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Something like `\draw (0,0) to[grid with coordinates,/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step x=.5] (5,1);  ` perhaps ...

Comment: Hello to you too!

Comment: Thanks for welcome! I hope I will not have to visit TeX.SE often ;]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the option

```
grid with coordinates/major step x=<value>
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\def\grd@save@target#1{%
  \def\grd@target{#1}}
\def\grd@save@start#1{%
  \def\grd@start{#1}}
\tikzset{
  grid with coordinates/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \edef\grd@@target{(\tikztotarget)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@target\grd@@target\relax
        \edef\grd@@start{(\tikztostart)}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@start\grd@@start\relax
        \draw[minor help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \draw[major help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
        \grd@start
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xa}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@ya}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \grd@target
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xb}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yb}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xc}{\grd@xa + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step x}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yc}{\grd@ya + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step y}}
        \foreach \x in {\grd@xa,\grd@xc,...,\grd@xb}
        \node[anchor=north] at (\x,\grd@ya) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
        \foreach \y in {\grd@ya,\grd@yc,...,\grd@yb}
        \node[anchor=east] at (\grd@xa,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}};
      }
    }
  },
  minor help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    gray,
    line cap =round,
    xstep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step x},
    ystep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step y}
  },
  major help lines/.style={
    help lines,
    line cap =round,
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major line width},
    xstep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step x},
    ystep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step y}
  },
  grid with coordinates/.cd,
  minor step x/.initial=.5,
  minor step y/.initial=.2,
  major step x/.initial=1,
  major step y/.initial=1,
  major line width/.initial=1pt,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=2]
    \draw (0,0) to[grid with coordinates] (5,1);    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A}\label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}    

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5,yscale=2,grid with coordinates/major step x=0.2]
    \draw (0,0) to[grid with coordinates] (1,1); %major step x =0.2
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{B}\label{fig:sphere}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Analogously, you can change `major step y`, `minor step x`, `minor step y`, and `major line width`.

Comment: I knew it's something simple, thank a lot! Is there some place (e.g. printed book, PDF, something...) you recommend to start creating/editing such code not with _trial and error_ method?

Comment: @MateuszDziedzic You're welcome. I guess you already know the [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for the basics? Other sources might be the sources of PGF/TikZ itself.

Comment: I'll look closer to **pgfmanual**, I somehow missed it.