# Remember coordinate in nested tikzpicture points to a weird place

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-qtree, coordinates, remember

I have problems with remembering the coordinates of names defined in nested tikz pictures.
Look at the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\inlinenode}[2]{
There are\\
several line\\
breaks\\
#2\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate (#1);\\
and #1 is not\\
in the center}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{Root}
        [.\node{\inlinenode{x1}{$x_1$}}; ]
        [.\node (x2) {$x_2$}; ]
      ]
\path[thick,color=red] (x1) edge (x2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of my minimal working example]

I want to connect x1 with x2 using the red line, which works fine for x2, but the other end is pointing in a weird place instead of to x1.

I have tried running pdflatex multiple times, but then the position of x1 gets even weirder.

What I want to achieve should be visible in the picture above, I want a multiline node with a special word/graphic inside the text and then connecting this word to another node (or even another special word inside another multiline text of a node).  Feel free to modify my approach.

I also tried replacing the `#2\tikz...\coordinate(#1)` with `\subnode{#1}{#2}` (as in [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149840/automatic-connection-of-text-points-in-tikz-qtree)), but this has the same result.

Comment: Nesting tikzpictures is a Bad Idea.  This sort of thing is what `subnode` is for since it is meant to define things as if there were nesting but without doing the actual nesting.  However, `tikz-qtree` actually does some nesting internally and this may be messing with how tikzmark and subnode work.  If no-one comes up with a better solution in the meantime, I'll do some digging and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tikz-qtree`, each child is actually a separate pgfpicture.  This means that when drawing between children in the way that you do, you are drawing between two different pgfpictures and so *both* need to have the `remember picture` key applied.

However, even then there are issues with the fact that you are nesting a `tikzpicture` inside the `pgfpicture` (which is itself nested in the main `tikzpicture`) and so just putting `remember picture` on the outermost `tikzpicture` does not work.  But this is exactly what the `\subnode` command from the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library was designed to deal with: it defines a subnode of a node without the rigmarole of setting up a whole new tikzpicture.

So using `\subnode` and `remember picture` we get:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153756/86}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\inlinenode}[2]{
There are\\
several line\\
breaks\\
\subnode{#1}{#2} \\
and #1 is not\\
in the center}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\Tree [.{Root}
        [.\node {\inlinenode{x1}{$x_1$}}; ]
        [.\node (x2) {$x_2$}; ]
      ]
\path[thick,color=red] (x1) edge (x2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz-qtree with subnode]