# alignment issue with tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
  q -- a,
  qb -- a,
  a -- b -- c -- g1,
  c -- g2,
  b -- g3,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) on a mac running macOS Sierra, I get this

[image]

But I would like `g1`, `g2` and `g3` to be vertically aligned. How would I do that? I tried to use `{[same layer] g1, g2, g3}` but then it gives

[image]

I would like to keep the angles exactly like those of the first diagram. With just the `b--g3` line longer to put `g3` aligned with `g1` and `g2`. I even tried `g3 [below=of g2]` but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry for the copy n' paste error. I have added precisions about my setup.

Comment: Sorry that edited... I thought it will ask you... feel free to go to your previous edition but I think this way is more accurate (just added tikz-feynman tag and changed the title to tikz-feynman)  I also would suggest to add luatex tag since my texlive gives different result

Comment: You might have to position the nodes by hand then.  The graphdrawing algorithms are good to have the nodes not overlap but manual positioning is basically impossible.

Comment: Actually, replacing `\usepackage{tikz-feynman}` by `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}`, `\usetikzlibrary{graphs}` and `\usegdlibrary{layered}`, I get the exact same behaviour. I was actually not using tikz-feynman per se: I just find it convenient an import because I know it pulls everything I usually need.

Comment: @koleygr As Luc says, this code doesn't actually use any of `tikz-feynman`s features, so the title change and tag doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok... feel free to change it again. It had sense at the time I added that. I could not reproduce it's result and also that was the only package used. I thought it had to do with this. Of course after Luc's answer the problem seems to be more general (with "graphs") and a change in title is recommended.  See here https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7391/edit-in-title-of-questions/7412#7412 what I just wrote on meta about such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force a node to be placed at a specific position on the canvas, after the node placement calculations have been completed. This is done with the `regardless at` syntax, which are described on p380 of the TikZ manual (v3.0.1a).

Node `q` is placed at the origin (0,0). With the graph set on a 1cm grid, it is then a simple matter of determining the appropriate co-ordinate for node `g3`.  We find that the co-ordinate is `(4,-2)`, which aligns `g3` with `g1` and `g2`.

So we can then write: `b -- g3[regardless at={(4,-2)}]` to add the node at the desired position. Following is the result, which incorporates a background grid ([How can I show coordinates by grid in TikZ automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39698/)) to illustrate the positioning of node `g3` at `(4,-2)`.

[image]

This is a MWE, modified from the original to show the libraries that are specifically required. The `Tikz-Feynman` package is not loaded since none of its macros are used. Note that use of the `TikZ` graph drawing libraries, requires `lualatex` to compile the code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}

\usetikzlibrary{
    graphs,
    graphdrawing,
}
\usegdlibrary{
    layered,   % requied for layered layout
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39698
\makeatletter
\def\grd@save@target#1{%
    \def\grd@target{#1}}
\def\grd@save@start#1{%
    \def\grd@start{#1}}
\tikzset{
    grid with coordinates/.style={
        to path={%
            \pgfextra{%
                \edef\grd@@target{(\tikztotarget)}%
                \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@target\grd@@target\relax
                \edef\grd@@start{(\tikztostart)}%
                \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@start\grd@@start\relax
                \draw[minor help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
                \draw[major help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
                \grd@start
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xa}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@ya}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
                \grd@target
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xb}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yb}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xc}{\grd@xa + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yc}{\grd@ya + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
                \foreach \x in {\grd@xa,\grd@xc,...,\grd@xb}
                \node[anchor=north,color=lightgray] at ([yshift=-0.15cm]\x,\grd@ya) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
                \foreach \y in {\grd@ya,\grd@yc,...,\grd@yb}
                \node[anchor=east,color=lightgray] at ([xshift=-0.15cm]\grd@xa,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}};
            }
        }
    },
    minor help lines/.style={
        help lines,
        step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step},
        minor line width/.initial=0.25pt,
    },
    major help lines/.style={
        help lines,
        line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major line width},
        step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step},
        line cap=round,
        color=lightgray,
    },
    grid with coordinates/.cd,
    minor step/.initial=.2,
    major step/.initial=1,
    major line width/.initial=0.5pt,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\tiny,
color=blue
]

\draw (0,-2) to[grid with coordinates] (4,1);

\graph[
layered layout, 
horizontal=a to b,
] {
  {q,qb} -- a,
  a -- b -- c,
  c -- {g1,g2},
  b -- g3[regardless at={(4,-2)}],
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You went the extra mile to be super helpful: thanks a lot!