# Reset nodestyle for tikzpicture in fancytikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters

## Problem

I'm using the gorgeous package [`fancytikzposter`](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html) to typeset my scientific posters. There I'd like to use `tikzpicture` to make sketches. Unfortunately the default Ti*k*Z styles are overwritten, such that I get awkwardly styled nodes.

## Minimal working example

To compile, you need to obtain [`fancytikzposter.sty`](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/tikz/fancytikzposter_sources.zip). Compile with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\initializesizeandshifts
\blocknode%
{A Ti\textit{k}Z picture}%
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[below] {$y$}
            (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[right] {$z$}
            (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left] {$x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output (cropped)

> [image]

**EDIT:** Bounty goes to the one, who fixes `fancytikzposter`.

Comment: It's an internal issue of `fancytikzposter` which is completely equal to: [tikzpicture in node of another tikzpicture: how to screen of from inheriting style?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/tikzpicture-in-node-of-another-tikzpicture-how-to-screen-of-from-inheriting-sty) So the author of `fancytikzposter` ought fix this issue with the provided solution of Martin's answer.

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Thank you very much. Is there a way I can temporarily fix that in `fancytikzposter.sty` for myself, or do I have to wrap every `tikzpicture` I have into a savebox?

Comment: Patching the package is very hard. The author provides only one big command to draw a blocknode named `\drawblocknode`. If you open the sty-file you will see there is a lot to do ;-). Maybe the author can optimise his code.

Comment: You can temporarily use `\tikzmark` macros to actually mark the places for your TikZ pictures and draw them outside the `\blocknode` if you can. It has a very strange construction choice for the whole thing so indeed it needs to be recoded. Here there is a recent update from that team; http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120988/3235 This is also what I meant in my answer here; http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116570/3235

Comment: I don not know if it is still helpfull, but I have faced the same problem with nested `tikzpicture` environments using `fancytikzposter`. The only way I was able to not end up with the default blocknodes from `tikzposter` was to make use of the node options. Explicitly calling for a rectangle node with `\node[rectangle, ...]` for example worked for me to get rid of the default blocknodes from `tikzposter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given by the comment of [Vedran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23079/vedran-ego) for [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex#comment394348_88768)

[`fancytikzposter`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancytikzposter) is obsolete and [`tikzposter`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikzposter)  is recommended instead.

A similar comment can be found on [Elena Botoeva's page](http://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Eebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html)

> NOTE that we joined our efforts with the tikzposter team, which resulted in an improved version 2.0 of the tikzposter class that you can find in http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter. This class combines both good structure and nice layouts. The official webpage of our project is https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki/ (under construction).
>
> I am not going to maintain this style.